# How to use input() in function()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, input

When I call the function using compound_interest(P, r, n, t) it shows error name P is not defined, why ?

```
def compound_interest(P, r, n, t):
    P=int(input())
    r=int(input())
    n=int(input())
    t=int(input())
    A=P*(1+r/n)**(n*t)
    return(f'Total Amount = {A}')

compound_interest(P, r, n, t)
```

Comment: Because you're trying to pass it into the function as an argument. Not all local variables need to be function arguments.

Answer (score 2):

**Best is first** : because a method should only compute things, from parameters and not asking new value

Either pass the values as parameters you'd get from another source of input in the main program

```
def compound_interest(P, r, n, t):
    A = P * (1 + r / n) ** (n * t)
    return f'Total Amount = {A}'

# call compound_interest(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Or you get the values from the `input()` inside the function so you don't need to passe them as parameters

```
def compound_interest():
    P = int(input("P: "))
    r = int(input("r: "))
    n = int(input("n: "))
    t = int(input("t: "))
    A = P * (1 + r / n) ** (n * t)
    return f'Total Amount = {A}'

# call compound_interest()
```